# Encountering issues when executing a command at terminal from python

Tags: python

I have the following command.

`/usr/bin/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs RequestURL.js https://www.ubank.com.au/ > body.html` which gets executed fine at the terminal, but does not get executed from python as follows.

```
def get_generated_html(self, url, has_headers):
        """
        Method: Method to get the generated HTML content from Phantomas.

        Args: Takes the url as an argument for which to get the HTML content.
              hasHeaders defaulted to false for no headers.

        Returns: Nothing.
        """
        if not urlparse(url).scheme:
            url = 'http://'+url
        if has_headers == False:
            command = PAGE_SOURCE_CMD % url
            utils.execute_command(command).communicate()
        else:
            command = FEO_PAGE_SOURCE_CMD % url
            print command
            utils.execute_command(command).communicate()
```

The print statement prints out the exact command.

Here is the execute_command() method.

```
def execute_command(command):
    """Executes the command and returns the process."""
    process = None
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print (
            'Process utility could not process %s'
            ' inside execute_command() method'
            % url)
    return process
```

I call the generated html as follows.

```
def start_parser(self, analysis_id, url, hasHeaders=False):
        """
        Method: Method to start the parser.

        Args: Analsyis ID and URL as an argument.

        Returns: Nothing.
        """

        feed = None
        path = self.create_analysis_folder(analysis_id, hasHeaders) 
        self.get_generated_html(url, hasHeaders)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.html'):
                    feed = BeautifulSoup(open(path + '/' +file).read())
                    if hasHeaders:
                        os.chdir('..')
                    print "deleting"
                    shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd())
            break
        return feed
```

The feed returned here is not the page source as it returns from command line.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with `PAGE_SOURCE_CMD` or they way `get_generated_html` is called? I can't see anything obviously wrong, so maybe some more context?

Comment: Added the call in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `get_generated_html` is supposed to do, but it doesn't return anything and it only `print`s in one of the cases. I'm confused by the docstring, since it says the function shouldn't return anything, but it doesn't say anyting about output either. The "defaults to false" part is not correct in the current code.

Also, [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns a tuple, so you will only return one of the elements of the return value (probably).

Try something like:

```
output = utils.execute_command(command).communicate()
return output[0]
```

If we are doing code review, this is more elegant to me:

```
if not has_headers:
    command = PAGE_SOURCE_CMD % url
else:
    command = FEO_PAGE_SOURCE_CMD % url
output = utils.execute_command(command).communicate()
return output[0]  # or print it?
```

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote? I think I answered the question ("Any help?").

Comment: executing the command from coammnd line prints the html source . From within the script it prints nothinh

Comment: Ok, so my comment about not printing or returning anything might be useful?